# Segundo comando não funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, condição

Estava testando as condições, mas quando utilizo um comando e depois outro, o segundo não está funcionando.

```
c=str(input(''))

if c == '/tutorial':
    print('ok, como vc é um hacker vc hackea td por comandos, para saber seus status vc precisa digitar /status')
    print('la vc sabera quanto dinheiro tem, qnt de sabedoria tem,em q lugar vc está e reputação')
    print('para saber oq vc pode hackear digite /hack, de acordo com seu conhecimento vc vai liberando mais coisas para hackear')
    print('de acordo com sua reputação vc é convocado a estudar em outras escolas e de acordo com a escola vc ganha mais pontos de conhecimento')
    print('para estudar utilize o /estudo boa sorte e FALOUUUU')
    c=''
    c = str(input(''))
elif c == '/status':
    print('dinheiro:{}  conhecimento:{}  reputação:{}  lugar onde estar:{}'.format(dinheiro,conhecimento,reputação,lugar))
    c=''
    c = str(input(''))
else:
    print('vc colocou o codigo errado e a policia te achou fim')
    c = str(input(''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Os comandos não funcionam seguidos porque estão numa estrutura `if` `else`, logo apenas um dos comandos será interpretado. No seu exemplo, se entrou logo no:

```
if c == '/tutorial':
```

Então já não vai entrar no:

```
elif c == '/status':
```

Pois isso era apenas se não tivesse entrado no `/tutorial`.

Uma solução passa por trocar todos os `elif` por `if` para analisar todos os comandos seguidos, mas acaba por ter que os fazer por ordem e sem poder repetir nenhum e repete o código de leitura do comando várias vezes. Melhor será fazer a leitura dos comandos num `while` e apenas terminar num caso especifico:

```
c=''

while c!='/sair': #terminar apenas com o comando /sair
    print('qual o comando ?')
    c=str(input(''))

    if c == '/tutorial':
        print('ok, como vc é um hacker vc hackea td por comandos, para saber seus status vc precisa digitar /status')
        print('la vc sabera quanto dinheiro tem, qnt de sabedoria tem,em q lugar vc está e reputação')
        print('para saber oq vc pode hackear digite /hack, de acordo com seu conhecimento vc vai liberando mais coisas para hackear')
        print('de acordo com sua reputação vc é convocado a estudar em outras escolas e de acordo com a escola vc ganha mais pontos de conhecimento')
        print('para estudar utilize o /estudo boa sorte e FALOUUUU')
    elif c == '/status':
        print('dinheiro:{}  conhecimento:{}  reputação:{}  lugar onde estar:{}'.format(dinheiro,conhecimento,reputação,lugar))
    else:
        #pode por break neste else se quiser terminar no primeiro comando inválido
        print('comando invalido')

    c = str(input('')) #voltar a ler outro comando

print('fim do jogo')
```

Comment: valeu:D..........